# Cryptic list object resentation in Python as [...]

Tags: python-3.x, list

I've run into this unseen list object, when I tried to play with list `append`, and I've searched hard but unable to find much information.  So this is what's happening:

```
L = ['dinosaur']
L.append(('theropoda', L))
print(L)
# ['dinosaur', ('theropoda',   [...])]
```

Questions - what's the [...] means here?   Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://www.sololearn.com/Discuss/1856497/python-append-a-list-to-the-same-list

Comment: I believe it indicates a circular list, you're appending L to L

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Glad there are experts here to help. Do you want to put it in the Answer so I can vote it?  (BtW - is there official doc.?)

Comment: Python prints a [...] whenever it detects a cycle in the object. when a collection object contains a reference to itself... 'and it try to avoid the stuck in an infinite loop. Good question.

Comment: this question needs a better title

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, Python will not attempt to include a circular/recursive reference in the representation of a `list`.

It would appear that the `__repr__` function (also used by `list`s to create the string for printing) is implemented via [`reprlib` with recursive support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/reprlib.html#reprlib.recursive_repr). Without it, you would end up with a `RecursionError` as to output the `list`, Python must include the nested version of the list, which also needs the nested version, and so on. Instead, it outputs the special value of `...` which indicates to you that it is a recursive reference.

Comment: Thanks, do you have the official doc. link?

Comment: The link in my answer is part of the official Python docs, is that what you need?